# why is Slacks interactive message not posting in JSON format?

Tags: slack-api, slack

The interactive message should be sending the in JSON format.

```
We'll send an HTTP POST request with information to this URL when users invoke message buttons. This URL must use the "https" protocol.
```

My request URL is the following , am I missing something?

```
https://admin:password@domain/api/v1/slack
```

Comment: Please specify what your question is. Do you receive a request from Slack at your script in the wrong format or do you not receive a request at all?

Comment: Yes , the request from Slack to my script is in  the wrong format.It is not in JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slack is not posting directly in JSON. It is sending a POST request to your script with a `payload` body parameter. This parameter contains an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded string with the request in JSON format. So be sure to first read the payload parameter for the JSON message.

Here is an example on how to read the `payload` paramter in PHP:

```
$payload_json = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'payload', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES );
$payload = json_decode ($payload_json, true);
```

See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#how_to_respond_to_message_button_actions) for the official documentation for examples.